# ¿Cómo evitar la selección en mi JTable en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo un boton para Agregar un Usuario Nuevo en mis base de datos.

La idea es la siguiente. Si el cliente hace clic en el JTable y selecciona un usuario existente e hace clic en el boton Agregar Nuevo Usuario, aparece SQLException ya que esos datos ya existen, entonces tenía pensando que, dentro del boton Agregar Nuevo Usuario, hacer algo para que el JTable no permita la selección en ese momento.

He probado pero, no funcionan:

```
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Si el usuario selecciona un registro de la tabla, entonces debería [*poblar* el formulario](http://www.kode-blog.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/swing_jdbc_gui.gif) con los datos de ese registro.

Comment: eso lo tengo pero, a la hora de ingresar un registro nuevo, y por equivocacion alguien selecciona una fila de la tabla y le hace clic al boton agregar, estará intentando registrar algo que ya existe, quiero evitar esto.

Comment: Lo evitas *deshabilitando* ese botón. Necesitarás un botón 'Cancelar' para volver a habilitarlo o con el evento que desees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que antes de agregar un usuario hagas las comprobaciones que necesites (una sería ver si existe). Luego si tienes que pasarle un mensaje al usuario lo haces mediante un mensaje emergente o como prefieras (en este caso sería "Ese usuario ya existe"), pero no uses una `Exception`.

Una excepción debe ocurrir cuando el programa no funciona como debería y se interrumpe e intentamos recuperarlo. Para un caso que ya esperas debes comunicarte entre métodos y avisar al usuario si tiene que hacer algo.

Yo en tu lugar traería a memoria los datos y en ella puedes tratar mejor la información con objetos `Usuario` y buscar qué identifica a cada usuario. ¿Un id? ¿Un nombre de dominio? No sé como quieres hacerlo.

Comment: para retornar eso debo primero hacer una sentencia que me compare el string que intentan guardar con todos los strings de la tabla?, suena complicado.

Comment: vale creo que he entendido, descargo todos los usuarios de la tabla y los comparo con el usuario que se intenta guardar, si hay dos iguales, envio un mensaje, got it. que hacemos con esta pregunta?, la editas con esa respuesta o la borro?.

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta para que quede claro como resolver tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

se me ocurre que no lo estas activando, es decir nunca entra a esa seccion de declaraciones, prueba asi:

```
system.out.println("entra1");
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
table.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
system.out.println("entra2");
```

para desactivar la columna

```
public class MiModelo extends DefaultTableModel
{
   public boolean isCellEditable (int row, int column)
   {
       // Aquí devolvemos true o false según queramos que una celda
       // identificada por fila,columna (row,column), sea o no editable
       if (column == 3)
          return true;
       return false;
   }
}
```

revisa este link: http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=JTable

Comment: si entra, recibo: entra1, entra2, en la consola. De hecho tengo otras cosas ahí y si funcionan pero, esto que quiero para el JTable no funciona.

Comment: @RobertGomez edite mi respuesta, te deje un link

Comment: lo he visto y eso es para que las celdas no puedan ser editables, ese no es mi problema. El problema mio es que en determinado momento al presionar un boton, el cliente no pueda seleccionar nada del JTable, ni filas, ni celdas, ni columnas.

Comment: @RobertGomez si haces lo mismo con las filas?

Comment: ya lo probé dentro de mi boton, y no funciona, todo sigue igual, puedes seleccionar cualquier cosa. :(

Comment: @RobertGomez creo que deberias aplicarlo al jtable